# Regularity of coefficients in a partial differential operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Following the text of Evans PDE, the topic on chapter 7 is Second Order Hyperbolic Equations, there is treated the following IBVP. Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ an open bounded set, $T>0$
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{r,l}
u_{tt} + Lu = f & U_T \\
u = 0 & \partial U \times [0,T] \\
u = g, u_t = h & U\times \{0\}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
where $f : U_T \to \mathbb{R}$;  $g,h : U \to \mathbb{R}$ and $u : \overline{U}_T \to \mathbb{R}$ is the unknown.
We also have that for each time $t$, $L$ is the second order partial differential operator defined as:
\begin{equation}
Lu = - \sum_{i,j} \left( a_{ij} u_{x_i}\right)_{x_j} + \sum_{i} b_i u_{x_i} + cu 
\end{equation}
My question is:
Why is it necessary to suppose that $a_{ij}, b_{i},c \in C^1 (\overline{U}_{T})$?

I tried to verify this but, I suppose it might be enough that $a_{ij}, b_{i},c \in L^{\infty}(U_T)$.

I got this idea doing the following, multiplying the initial equation by $\phi \in C_{c}^{\infty}(U)$, then integrating by parts on $U$ we have
\begin{equation}
\int_U u_{tt}  \phi \, dx + \sum_{i,j} \int_U a_{ij} u_{x_i}  \phi_{x_j} \,dx + \sum_{i} \int_U b_i  u_{x_i} \phi \, dx + \int_U c u \phi \,dx = \int_U f \phi \,dx
\end{equation}
Now, since $\phi \in C_{c}^{\infty}(U)$, then $a_{ij}u_{x_i}, b_i u_{x_i}, cu \in L_{Loc}^{1}(U)$, thereupon $a_{ij}, b_i, c \in L^{\infty}(U_T)$.

Is it something wrong with this procedure? Or did I miss something there?
Thanks.